# ASP classic & SQL Server 2014 decimal type as parameter for stored procedure

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, decimal, sql-server-2014

I'm working with an old ASP Classic site which has recently gone from SQL Server 2005 to 2014 and I can not seem to pass a variable in as a decimal.

I've broken what I'm working with down to a test procedure which takes a `decimal(4,2)` and returns a `varchar` cast of it (real stored procedure does more work)

`decimalV` is `14.5` in this example

```vb
Const AdNumeric = 131
Const AdParamInput = &H0001

Response.Write("decimalV: " & decimalV & "<br>")

oCmd.Parameters.Append = oCmd.CreateParameter("@test", AdNumeric, adParamInput,, decimalV)
    oCmd.Parameters("@test").Precision=2
    oCmd.Parameters("@test").NumericScale=4
oCmd.Parameters.Append = oCmd.CreateParameter("@varcharBack", AdVarChar, AdParamOutput, 40)
```

My understanding is that the precision is the decimal places and the `NumericScale` is the number of digits.

I get the output:

```
decimalV: 14,5
```

followed by the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e21' 

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value,
if available. No work was done.
```

I've switched to European, for a `.` and tried to cast the input variable to both a `Cdbl` and a `CStr`.

If I set the `Precision` to 4 and the `NumericScale` to 2 I get 1500 as the cast return.

The SQL for this is below. Again, this is only a basic dummy, the real SQL does more but for the decimal it just uses it to update another decimal of the same sort in a table.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.testDecimal
    @test DECIMAL(4,2),
    @varcharBack VARCHAR(40) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @varcharBack = CAST(@test AS VARCHAR(40));
END
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, I suspect that's more an odbc problem than a sql server one. This might get you somewhere. http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214854

Comment: Thanks changed the tags on the post. I'll go the google on odbc.

Comment: You're using a an old provider, switch to using the SQL Server Native Client. Although there is no SQL Server 2014 example on [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) it shouldn't be any different to [SQL Server 2012](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/standard-security/).

Comment: Just [confirmed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280510.aspx) *"SQL Server 2014 installs SQL Server 2012 Native Client. There is no SQL Server 2014 Native Client"* so my links above should help.

Comment: Also when mapping data types from SQL Server to ADODB I have always used this very useful resource [Data Type Mapping](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx). If you are specifying `DECIMAL(4, 2)` you should be using `adNumeric` as your data type in the `CreateParameter()` method. Especially once you switch to using SQL Server Native Client.

Comment: My apologies (Lankymart), I was using AdNumeric for everything first, the AdDecimal was a last ditch trial (on my part) from a collegue who had used that for a different datatype. I don't (technically) have access to the connection string so I need to talk to our lead developer about it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to change the connection strings so ended up solving this by passing a double into the stored procedure (after client-side validation) and then casting the FLOAT to a DECIMAL(4,2).